# How to position in parallel navigation bar and logo

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<body>
    <header id="masthead">
        <div id="container">
            <!-- logo -->
            <img src="logo.png" alt="" width="200px" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about us.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="developers.html">About Developers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="economy.html">Economy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="study.html">Why Study in Dublin?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="people_culture.html">People and Culture</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
```

And this CSS code:

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo   {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

header::after {
    content : '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 2px;
  
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0.1rem;
  }

nav a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

However I want to make my nav bar to the left from the logo, but not down below. How can I do it using the given initial code that i hav pointed ? As you can see, `align: right` and `align: left` has been used, but had not helped me

Like on photo (Used arrows to point it )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create two columns. In one column, place your logo, and in the second column, place your navigation bar.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa; width:20%;">
 <!--pLACE Logo here--->
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb; width:80%">
   <!--Place Navbar code here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Remember Adjust your css accordingly**

Answer (score 0):

Give your div with id `container` a display property of `flex`, direction property of `row` and then align or justify items as per your liking

```
#container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Also in your HTML code you've given tags `ids` but you're using `class` selectors in your CSS

Some resources that'll help you:

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Basic Concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

[Flexbox Cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#section-display)

Comment: More info on CSS selectors : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your `CSS` as shown below:

```
/*add this line to adjust paddings on the columns and remove default margin padding for all the html elements*/
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

/*change class to # it's ID and not class*/
        #container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

/*recommended to add width in percentage in css and remove fix width from <img width='200px' /> tag*/
        .logo {
            float: left;
            width:20%;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }

/*add width 80% for <nav> tag*/
        nav {
            float: right;
            width: 80%;
            margin-top: 10%;
        }


        nav li {
            display: inline-block;
            /* margin-left: 70px; */ /*remove*/
            /* padding-top: 2px; */ /*remove*/
            position: relative;
            /* padding-right: 0.1rem; */ /*remove*/
            padding: 0 5px; /*instead add this for space between li content*/
        }
```

I would recommend you to use `CSS FLEXBOX`.

Answer (score -1):

I used flexbox to do this. your `id="container"` was not the same as the CSS so I changed it to `class="container"`
I added some simple `1px` borders just to illustrate what is where on the page.

This is likely not a finished solution and only a starting point.

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: space-between font-size: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li::before {
  content: "\200B";
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-right: 0.1rem;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav li a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header id="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo png" width="200px" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="developers.html">About Developers</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="economy.html">Economy</a></li>
        <li><a href="study.html">Why Study in Dublin?</a></li>
        <li><a href="people_culture.html">People and Culture</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```